# How to propose a project

Tags: communication, project-proposal

I've been with a company for a year now, and I work closely with the company owners (its a startup).  I've had an idea for a project that I want to propose, but I wasn't sure the best way to pass the idea and make a good impression.

I was thinking of writing up a business plan for the project and presenting that, however, I wasn't sure if that would be overkill.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done and what are you afraid of in just pitching it directly as an idea?

Comment: I've done enough research to write a complete business plan for the project.  My fear is that it will get brushed off if I just throw the idea out.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a project management *process* issue. Perhaps it's a workplace issue that belongs on http://workplace.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm confused. On one side you say you work closely with them which suggests you could informally pitch something. On the other, you feel you might need a business plan to propose a project. Is the question truly about a challenge in proposal/project initiation or is it more about entering new territory in your relationship with the owners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try a pitch deck

It looks to me that the project charter and business justification are part of the PM process.

While tradionally formal business plans were needed for such a discussion, in start-up circles nobody uses them at this stage in the game. The "pitch deck" is the favored option. It is really a few presentation slides that highlight the essence of the business plan. Just search for "pitch deck" and you will get plenty of info.